# change src attribute with angular 2 WITHOUT JQUERY

Tags: angular

I have this images:

```
<div class="image-index-container">
                    <div>
                        <img class='index-pics' src="images/yourbag.png" alt="">
                        <p class="activeIndex">Your Bag</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div style="width: 13%">
                        <img class='index-pics' src="images/delivery-gray.png" alt="">
                        <p>Delivery Details</p>
                    </div>
</div>
```

when I click on one button I want to change the src attribute from images/yourbag to images/yourbag-gray and the img with the src images/delivery-gray to images/delivery.

in addition to  remove the class activeIndex from the first text and add it to the second one without using JQuery

Answer (score 2):

do it like this using this  `[src]="imageUrl"`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
    <img class='index-pics' [src]="imgsrc" alt="">
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="btnClick()">change</button>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  imgsrc="http://az866755.vo.msecnd.net/product/1468402190267-product.jpeg"

  btnClick()
  {
   this.imgsrc="http://az866755.vo.msecnd.net/product/1454067764999-product.jpeg" 
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: What if my image has an imgsrc and srcset like:  srcset="images/ic-add-copy-3@2x.png 2x, 
                images/ic-add-copy-3@3x.png 3x"? same approach?

Comment: use [srcset] like this

Answer (score 1):

Use `src="{{path}}"` and Angular will update the path.
For example

```
<button (onclick)="path=newpath"><button>
```

Another example

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
<h3>Github Users:{{[].concat(users).length}} </h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users" style="list-style:none">
   <button (click)="data = user" style="cursor:pointer"> <img  src="{{user.avatar_url}}" style="height:200px; width:250px;" /></button>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<md-card class="col-lg-8 " *ngIf="data" style="position:fixed; margin-left:22%; margin-top:3.5%">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
  <img  src="{{data.avatar_url}}" style="height:200px; width:250px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
{{data | json}}
 </div>
</md-card>
```